# Cannot start Portainer which compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I don't know why but I cannot start [portainer](https://portainer.io/).

I downloaded https://github.com/portainer/portainer-compose

I did a `docker-compose up`

Everything seems fine:

```
portainer-proxy
docker ps                                                                                 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED         
9c01c18dcc23        portainer/portainer:latest   "/portainer --temp..."   5 minutes ago   
2de6b22cadb0        portainer_proxy              "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   10 minutes ago  
1c0166b3f870        v2tec/watchtower             "/watchtower --cle..."   10 minutes ago  
893a507f62e3        portainer/templates          "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   10 minutes ago
```

And I have this in the logs :

```
portainer-app | 2017/11/12 15:01:54 Warning: the --templates / -t flag is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
portainer-app | 2017/11/12 15:01:54 Starting Portainer 1.15.1 on :9000
```

I should be able to access portainer on port 9000, but nothing happens here.

If I try to access localhost then I have 404 from nginx.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I you would like to access port 9000 from Portainer, you need to expose it firstly. Edit Portainer-compose docker-compose.yml. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ports

Answer (score 1):

In the doc of the partainer compose, the link to access to partainer is: http://localhost/portainer  (replace localhost by the ip of your server if necessary). So it uses the 80 port.
If you need to use the 9000 port, replace this line ine the docker-compose.yml:

```
ports:
  - "80:80"
```

by

```
ports:
  - "9000:80"
```

And access to it: http://localhost:9000/portainer

HTH